# Cancelling Jenkins Job from Command line (CLI)

Tags: jenkins

Just like 'build' command is used to start a job from Jenkins CLI, is there a way to cancel a long running job using CLI or any other command line technique. This I am trying in a windows machine and I am not looking to directly kill the process from task manager or shut down the jenkins.
Please suggest.

Comment: I think that with an exit on error in batch script should stop the job.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please give me an example? By the way, I am running the job as a background process.

Comment: exit /b <errorlevel> is for exit a script/command. this should stop the jenkins job that runs the script.

Comment: This doesn't help. As I am starting the job once from cmd, the job is started in jenkins and this command is not impacting the jenkins job which continues running. I hope there should be cli command to hit the jenkins job for stopping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop a Jenkins execution by calling JOB_URL/lastBuild/stop

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins built-in Command Line tool does not provide a way to cancel/stop/abort a running build. But fortunately jenkins has provided other script API like **Python API** and **Ruby API** which have such ability.

#### Python API

> class jenkinsapi.build.Build(url, buildno, job, depth=1)

```
stop()  
Stops the build execution if it’s running :
return boolean True if succeded    
False otherwise or the build is not running
```

API Link:https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html

#### Ruby API

> Class: JenkinsApi::Client::Job

```
#stop_build(job_name, build_number = 0) ⇒ Object (also: #stop, #abort)
Stops a running build of a job This method will stop the current/most recent build if no build number is specified.
```

API Link: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jenkins_api_client/1.4.2/JenkinsApi/Client/Job

Answer (score 0):

This option assumes you have access to the Jenkins installation.

In Jenkins >2.195 you can do this using the Jenkins CLI jar:

```sh
# Export JENKINS_URL or add -s http://localhost[:port]/path/to/jenkins to the commands
export JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080/jenkins

# Get the name of the job you want to cancel
java -jar /path/to/jenkins-cli.jar -auth user:secret list-jobs

# Cancel the job
java -jar /path/to/jenkins-cli.jar -auth user:secret stop_builds <job_name>

# You can also disable the job, if needed
java -jar /path/to/jenkins-cli.jar -auth user:secret disable_job <job_name>
```