# Cancel Jenkins job if TFS Build Definition that queued it was cancelled

Tags: jenkins, tfs, build-definition

I have a TFS Build Definition which has a Queue Jenkins job step. If I cancel the TFS Build Definition the Jenkins job isn't cancelled. Is there a way to make it cancel?

I'm thinking maybe schedule a step to run if build definition was cancelled which cancels the job using [Cancelling Jenkins Job from Command line (CLI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954664/cancelling-jenkins-job-from-command-line-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "Jenkins stop job" task, using Jenkins API like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954664/cancelling-jenkins-job-from-command-line-cli) or with POST call like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021905/how-to-stop-a-build-in-jenkins-via-the-rest-api).

Configure this task to run only if you cancel the build:

[image]

```
eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled')
```